# Inconsistent File Representation in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am currently experiencing an unusual behavior in Visual Studio Code.

The issue is that when navigating to a function definition in my code, which is defined in another file tab which is already open, a new Tab with the same content opens. Both tabs seem to be referencing the same file object. This means that changes made in one tab are also visible in the other, and vice versa.

Here are some details and steps I have already taken:

- I have reinstalled Visual Studio Code and set up a new project to ensure that the issue is not project-specific.
- All extensions have been temporarily disabled to rule out conflicts.
- The Visual Studio Code cache has been cleared, and the program has been restarted multiple times.
- I have changed and adapted the settings.json file. I do not know if this is helpful but here is the content of the file:

```json
{
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {},
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [],
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [],
    "python.condaPath": "C:\\Users\\...\\anaconda3\\Scripts\\conda-script.py",
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "c:\\Users\\...\\anaconda3\\envs\\work\\python.exe",
    "python.experiments.optInto": [ "pythonTerminalEnvVarActivation" ],
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\...\\anaconda3\\python.exe",
    "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
    "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
    "python.experiments.enabled": true,
    "security.restrictUNCAccess": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
}
```

This behavior doesn't seem to align with the normal workflow of Visual Studio Code, and I am unsure how to further investigate or resolve it. Please provide guidance or recommendations on how to address this issue.

As for extensions, I'm using the ones displayed in the attached image. However, since I'm collaborating on a group project, my group members use different extensions. Interestingly, they are also experiencing the same issue after pulling my latest version from GitHub. This is perplexing to me because the settings aren't part of the GitHub repository, and there are no hardcoded file paths in my code.

[image]

For a more detailed problem description, I've included additional images.

In these images, you can observe that two excel_try files are open. The path of the first one shows as `\\raven\Files\Maxi\GitHub\excel_try.py`, and the path of the second one is `V:\Maxi\GitHub\excel_try.py`. Raven is an external network stored under the V: drive.

Let me give an example: The function `A` is defined in the `excel_try` file. I am utilizing this function in the `main_GUI` file. However, when I attempt to view the definition of function `A` by clicking on it in `main`, Visual Studio directs me to the file located at `\\raven\Files\Maxi\GitHub\excel_try.py`. Yet, when I manually open the file from the project's file explorer, a different (or apparently the same) `excel_try` file located at `V:\Maxi\GitHub\excel_try.py` is displayed.

I regret to inform you that my GitHub project is currently a work in progress and is not intended for public access at this time.

[image]

Comment: you mist have mapped the `\\raven\Files` to the `V:` drive and opened the `\\raven\Files` as your workspace, open the `V:` version as your workspace

Comment: But I have just one workspace open. The \\raven\Files is mapped top V:\ but how can I solve this problem now ?

Comment: open the workspace in 2 different ways by `V:` or by `\\raven` and see which does not have the behavior, if both have: file an issue at the VSC repo

Comment: Did you look at issues on the VSCode repository on GitHub? I would open an issue there. Stackoverflow is not the right place for this.

Comment: @CanH.Tartanoglu https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426660/11107541

Answer (score 1):

The two paths you're seeing (`\\raven\Files\Maxi\GitHub\excel_try.py` and `V:\Maxi\GitHub\excel_try.py`) are actually the same file.

The first is the UNC path, and the second is the mapped network drive path.

When you open a file in VS Code, it uses the path you provided to locate the file. When you navigate to a function definition, VS Code uses the Python language server to find the file, which might be resolving the network path to its UNC form.

Here's a possible solution. You could use the "File > Open Folder" menu to open your project folder through the network drive (V:). And then open your Python files from the file explorer in VSCode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Regarding your possible solution: that's what I've been doing. But the problem is when navigating to the definition of a function via strg+click on function VSC opens a second tab of the same file. As you can see at the image above, I have 2 excel_try.py files open. The first one appears clicking on the file at the file explorer and the second one when navigating to the functions definition.